# using rolling functions on multi-index dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a multi-index dataframe in pandas, where index is on ID and timestamp. I want to be able to compute a time-series rolling sum of each ID but I can't seem to figure out how to do it without loops.

```
content = io.BytesIO("""\
IDs    timestamp     value
0      2010-10-30     1
0      2010-11-30     2
0      2011-11-30     3
1      2000-01-01     300
1      2007-01-01     33
1      2010-01-01     400
2      2000-01-01     11""")
df = pd.read_table(content, header=0, sep='\s+', parse_dates=[1])
df.set_index(['IDs', 'timestamp'], inplace=True)
pd.stats.moments.rolling_sum(df,window=2
```

And the output for this is:

```
                value
IDs timestamp
0   2010-10-30    NaN
    2010-11-30      3
    2011-11-30      5
1   2000-01-01    303
    2007-01-01    333
    2010-01-01    433
2   2000-01-01    411
```

Notice the overlap between IDs 0 and 1 and 1 and 2 at the edges (I don't want that, messes up my calculations).  One possible way to get around this is to use groupby on IDs and then loop through that groupby and then apply a rolling_sum.

I am sure there is a function to help me do this without using loops.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Group first, then roll the sum (also `rolling_sum` is available in the top-level namespace)

```
In [18]: df.groupby(level='IDs').apply(lambda x: pd.rolling_sum(x,2))
Out[18]: 
                value
IDs timestamp        
0   2010-10-30    NaN
    2010-11-30      3
    2011-11-30      5
1   2000-01-01    NaN
    2007-01-01    333
    2010-01-01    433
2   2000-01-01    NaN
```

Comment: Seems like pd.rolling_sum will be deprecated in the future, so ahead of that, the updated method for the above answer would be:

    `df.groupby(level='IDs').apply(lambda x: x.rolling(window=2).sum())`

Comment: updated for pandas >= 1.0: `df.groupby(level='IDs', group_keys=False).rolling(2).sum()`